# How to select thead element from dynamically built table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have dynamically built table in JavaScript/JQUERY. After table is built I need to select `thead` element. Here is example of my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  buildTbl();
});

function buildTbl() {
  var tbl = '<table id="myTbl"><thead><tr><th>Column 1</th></tr></thead><tr><td>Cell 1</td></tr><tbody></tbody></table>';
  $('#tblContainer').empty().append(tbl);
  var test = $('#myTbl').find('thead');
  console.log(test);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tblContainer'></div>
```

As you can see in example in console length is `0`. The element is not selected. I'm wondering how I can access dynamically built elements in JavaScript? I need to prevent headers from scrolling so that's why I need to select `thead` element int he table.

Comment: `$('#myTbl')` knows nothing about the html in your string varible...it looks in the DOM for such element. Insert the table html in dom or explain more about what you are trying to do

Comment: `tbl` variable is unused in your code

Comment: I apologize for missing to show the code on how to attach `tbl` to DOM. In my example that works just fine now using `empy()` and `append()` methods. In original code that I found in the project that I'm working on they used `.html()`. Seems that was causing the problem and I couldn't detect element in the dom. I'm not sure if `.html()` is good practice to use in this case. Thank you.

Comment: No reason `html()` shouldn't work

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure then why selector didn't catch the table.

Comment: change your demo in question to `html()` and it works fine. My guess is there is some ajax not shown and the sequence is different in your real code

Comment: @charlietfl I will test with `.html()` one more time. It's an old code not well organized and I might missed something. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I suggest you another way of creating your element. As you are using jquery you can use jquery to create your html node as follow so that you can access to your jquery element before appending it into the `dom`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  buildTbl();
});

function buildTbl() {
  var $tbl = $("table").attr("id", "myTbl");
  var $thead = $("thead");
  // TODO: Here you can add your table rows into your thead
  $tbl.append($thead);
  // now you can access to your thead element without searching the dom.
  console.log($thead);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append it to the dom before you want to retrieve it using selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  buildTbl();
});

function buildTbl() {
  var tbl = '<table id="myTbl"><thead><tr><th>Column 1</th></tr></thead><tr><td>Cell 1</td></tr><tbody></tbody></table>';
  $('#tableContainer').append(tbl)


  var test = $('#myTbl').find('thead');
  console.log(test);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tableContainer'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This and call buildTbl before $(document).ready()

```
function buildTbl() {
     var tbl = '<table id="myTbl"><thead><tr><th>Column 1</th></tr></thead><tr><td>Cell 1</td></tr><tbody></tbody></table>';

     $('#tableContainer').html(tbl)
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
   buildTbl();

   var test = $(document).find('#myTbl > thead');
   console.log(test);
});
```

And call the div with id tableContainer

**Hope this will help you**